# Overriding Magento Adminhtml Controller in app/code/local Folder

Tags: magento

I would like to override the Magento Admin core controller in `app/code/local` folder.

I need to override the `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php`

in `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php` path.

i have copied the core files and created the same path in local folder.

Still the files are not loading from local folder, it only loading from core files.

I have cleared the Magento cache and set the File permission(777) for all folder in `app/code/local` directory.

Can any one suggest me the solution for this issues?

Any help much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento controllers are not autoloaded the same as other classes (blocks, models etc.), if you wish to overload it, your best bet is to [configure your own controller to get checked before it in the routing](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller).

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you how i have overridden customer controller

in app/code/local/'your company'/'your module name'/etc/config.xml

enable custom module

`<config>
       <modules>
           <company_module>
               <active>true</active>
               <codePool>local</codePool>
        </company_module>
        </modules>
    </config>`

Route custom module path

`<frontend>
    <routers>
        <company_module>
             <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                     <module>company_module</module>
                     <frontName>customer</frontName>
                </args>
         </company_module>
    </routers>
</frontend>`

rewrite class

`<global>
    <rewrite>
        <company_module_address>
                <from><![CDATA[#^/address/#]]></from>
                <to>/customer/address/</to>
        </company_module_address>
    </rewrite>
</global>`

at app/code/local/company/module/controllers/AddressController.php

`<?php`

`require_once 'Mage/Customer/controllers/AddressController.php';`

`class Company_Module_AddressController extends Mage_Customer_AddressController
{
    //Show your magic here 
}`

Hope this helps... Thanks